# Shortcode not working with Wordpress updated

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to learn wordpress and php development. I have been trying to create my own shortcode to add a json pull that I can parse into scheduled posts. I have the base php working - I've been experimenting in phpfiddle.org but as soon as I add anything specific to wordpress things stop. I am posting this as a new question because it seems like the latest WP update is causing a lot of issues.

I am adding this code to functions.php:

```
add_shortcode('aggrenda', 'aggrenda_func');
function requestAggrendaEvents() {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://aggrenda.com/mpellas/michael-pellas/events.json");
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    return $data['events'];
}

function getPostInfo($aggrendaEvent) {
    return array(
        "title" => $aggrendaEvent['title'],
        "description" => $aggrendaEvent['description'],
    );
}

// Get the aggrenda events as an associative array
$aggrendaEvents = requestAggrendaEvents();

// Get the WordPress post information for the "next" event in Aggrenda
$postInfo = getPostInfo($aggrendaEvents[0]);

// TODO: Create a post using $postInfo
echo $postInfo['title'], '<br>';
echo $postInfo['description'], '<br>';

// See what exactly is in $postInfo right now
var_dump($postInfo);
```

I'm sure i'm missing something small. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the brackets and adding the full url:

```
$url = 'http://theurl.com';
```

And for clarity, it's best to use different names for the tag and function name:

```
add_shortcode('aggrenda', 'aggrenda_func');
function aggrenda_func() {

    $url = 'http://theurl.com';

    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );

    echo($response);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the response. I did that and am now only getting a response with "array"...

Comment: OK...I used print_r instead of echo and i can now see the array. Next, I have to try and parse it.

Comment: Please accept the answer. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Sorry I didn't earlier...another rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: I edited my orginal post for updated code. I tried it in phpfiddle.org and it works fine at pulling the string. I use it in functions.php and it pulls the string but not in a post...just a blank page shows up with the json string. If I change file_get_contents with wp_remote_get I get a null return. I need this JSON array in a WP post...

Comment: You should var_dump the json array. And maybe share it here. You probably have an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks. If I write this in pure PHP it works: '$json = file_get_contents("http://aggrenda.com/mpellas/michael-pellas/events.json");
 $data = json_decode($json, true);
 var_dump($data['events'][1]['title']);  but if I do 'add_shortcode('aggrenda', 'requestAggrendaEvents');
function requestAggrendaEvents() 
 {
 $json = wp_remote_get("http://aggrenda.com/mpellas/michael-pellas/events.json");
 $data = json_decode($json, true);
 var_dump($data['events'][1]['title']); I get nothing... what am I missing

Comment: Then dump and $json and / or $data and check the contents/structure.

Comment: Thank you for your help today...i really appreciate it. I posted another question after your previous content just to make sure.